# Cannot Access a Shared Folder Using Windows 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, nas

I have a NAS drive, and this is sharing some folders. I cannot access those folders from a windows 2008 machine which is on the network. The are both connected to the same network switch.

e.g. if I go like `\\\\server\` or `\\\\server\folder`

I get the message:

> windows cannot access \\server check the spelling, click diagnose
>
> Error code: 0x80004005

The thing is that I can connect to this shared drive from a Windows 7 laptop connected wirelessly to the same network.

I can ping the server from windows 2008, but only if I use the IP address, not the server name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really found an answer here. The answer is to use ftp with the NAS drive from that particular computer :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you map it by \\IP\sharename ?

It sounds to me like your wireless clients are using a different DNS server than your 2008 machine.

Comment: Nah, cannot even do it using the IP address. Strange eh.

Comment: \\192.168.1.250\ etc

Answer (score 0):

If it is synology nas you might check your SMB version.
On the synology go to [Control Panel] > [File Services] > [SMB/AFP/NFS]

The option [Enable SMB service] should be enabled. 
Click the [Advanced Settings] button.

In my case the "Maximum SMB protocol" and "Minimum SMB protocol" were set to SMB1. 
I changed the Maximum SMB protocol to SMB3 and now I can access the share perfectly from my Windows 10 pc.